# Интеграл по контуру с комплексной переменной

Tags: математика

Уважаемые дамы и господа, не могу найти нормальный источник, который объяснил бы как это решать. На сайте университета ничего толкового не нашел, как и в остальном интернете.

Будте любезны, расскажите(или киньте ссылку), как это работает. Спасибо.

[image: Интеграл по контуру с комплексной переменной]

Comment: Рассказывать - долго и непонятно, с какого уровня начинать... Возьмите учебник по ТФКП, посмотрите интеграл по контуру, вычеты, интегральную формулу Коши... Если про*гугл*яться - то легко найти. Ну вот, например - http://window.edu.ru/resource/084/19084/files/metod483.pdf или http://www.apmath.spbu.ru.../ru/staff/starkov/tfkp-part2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кому-нибудь интересно, то вот решение.[image: Решение интеграла]